# Map.AddIndex() throws Hazelcast Unhandled Exception in Hazelcast .Net Client

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I need to add index on certain portable fields of type string, date, int on the fly in IMap.

1. Firstly, while adding index to the Map which holds certain entries throws Hazelcast Unhandled Exception stating that could not find PortableFactory for factory-id: XXX.
2. Secondly I tried an other way of adding index before loading entries to the map and found no issues at the time of adding index but while setting an entry again I got the same exception as stated above. But surprisingly I found a record inside the map with that exception scenario.

Did adding index for portable objects expecting the class definitions on server side? But for Portable Serialization there is no need to have the class definitions at server end as per the doc.

**Member Config:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="true">http://localhost:8085/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>           
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>           
            <discovery-strategies>
            </discovery-strategies>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>       
    </network>   
    <map name="default">       
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>                       
        <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>
    </map>     
    <serialization>
        <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    </serialization>
    <services enable-defaults="true"/>
    <lite-member enabled="false"/>
</hazelcast>
```

**Please find the client code below:**

```html
private static void DoMapIndexing()
{
IMap<TKey, TValue> map = GetMap<TKey, TValue>("testMap"); 
map.AddIndex("name", false);
map.AddIndex("DOB", true);
}

private static IMap<TKey, TValue> GetMap<TKey, TValue>(string mapName)
{
IHazelcastInstance client = getHazelcastClientConnection();
return client.GetMap<TKey, TValue>(mapName);
}

private static IHazelcastInstance getHazelcastClientConnection()
{
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.GetNetworkConfig().AddAddress("x.x.x.x");
IDictionary<int, IPortableFactory> factoryClasses = new Dictionary<int, IPortableFactory>();
factoryClasses.Add(2000, new BusinessObjectPortableFactory());
config.GetSerializationConfig().SetPortableFactories(factoryClasses);
return HazelcastClient.NewHazelcastClient(config);
}
```

Comment: Please, attach your config for Java member and .NET client

Comment: Please, find the config for member and programmatic config code for client in the updated post.

Comment: Apparently, `BusinessObjectPortableFactory` is missing in Java config.

Comment: But, without Java config it is possible to put the data in IMap and apply predicates on it. Please let me know what goes wrong?

Comment: Could you share your test app somewhere? I need to look at all parts. Thanks